# Is there high performance data structure for sparse bit map set semantic queries?

Tags: c++, performance, data-structures, bitmap, sparse-matrix

I'm working on a data which could (logically) considered as a sparse bit map,
`d_k = (f_0, f_1, ..., f_n)`,
which satisfies:

- `f_i` are bit, thus all `d_k` is actually something like 010010001...
- length of `d_k`, or maximum index `n` in `f_n`, is not statically konwn, requires user input at runtime. But typically it would be around 1000 ~ 10000.
- all `d_k` are sparse, maximum number of non-zero `f_i` in each `d_k` could be considdered less than 1024 in all cases, and in most cases it might be less than 64, which is significally less than its length.
- Which bit in `d_k` is 1 is completely random, **no** relation like "1 is continues in sparse bitmap" etc.
- `d_k` is completely determined by its bits `( ... f_i ...)`, thus if `d_i` and `d_j` has same bit map, there are considered to be same.
- need to support insert a bitmap `(f_0, f_1, ...)` and return a integer `d_k` as handle
- need to support lookup bitmap via its handle
- need to support query "given a bitmap `q = (f_q0, f_q1, ...)` find all `d_k`s which **all** 1-bits in q are 1", or equvilantly "find all d_k, where `d_k`'s bitmap bitand q = q"
- need to support query "given a bitmap `q = (f_q0, f_q1, ...)` find all `d_k`s which **all** 1-bits in q are 0", or equvilantly "find all d_k, where `d_k`'s bitmap bitand q = 0"
- need to support query (but less importantly, and could be slower) "given a bitmap `q = (f_q0, f_q1, ...)` find all `d_k`s which **any** 1-bits in q are 1", or equvilantly "find all d_k, where `d_k`'s bitmap bitand `q > 0`"

Is there a high performance data structure for this kind of data and queries?

Comment: When changing representation of a bitmap (through encoding) there is always a cost overhead. So you need to know up front if you want te be able to restore the original image too (and how often it is "compressed" vs. "decompressed"). How many images you can keep decompressed etc. So it is not only about the data structure it is also about how it is going to be used (and how well it fits in cache etc). In the end, after designing, the only thing that really matters is profiling (measure measure measure... and get rid of your bottlenecks).

Comment: Use `std::unordered_set<std::uint16_t>` to store the indice of **ON** bits. Any bit not in the set is **OFF**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sparse bitmaps, the choice is between storing all the bits (e.g. using `std::vector`) versus just storing the indices of the set bits (e.g. using `std::set`). The performance of each option depends heavily on the sparseness of the bits and the mix of operations. I recommend developing a performance benchmark for your actual data to help drive design decisions.

Let's call the maximum index N and the number of set bits S. The full bitmap requires ~N/8 bytes to store while the indices require ~4S bytes. The crossover point is around N = ~32S.

For computing an intersection, the full bitmap requires 3N/64 operations (assuming a 64 bit platform) while the indices requires 3S operations. This puts the crossover point around N = ~64S. Iterating over the bitmap will be faster than intersecting the two sets of indices per operation, so you definitely need the sparseness to be higher than 1:64 for indices to be faster.

Given the numbers in your question, I really think the only way to make a determination is to do some benchmarking because the problem size seems to be somewhere in the middle ground. As N increase and S decreases, using indices will get better relative to the full bitmap, but performance on modern hardware is often counter-intuitive so you can't make the decision a priori.

### Update

I ran some simple performance tests for creating and intersecting bitmaps using `BitMap` (a simple `std::vector`-based implementation), `std::set`, and `std::unordered_set`. I used 10k bits with sparsity from 1:16 through 1:1024.

As one might expect, `BitMap` is much faster for creation while `std::unordered_set` is much faster at intersection with `std::unordered_set` strictly dominating `std::set` in both tests as shown in the following plots.

[image: bitmap creation]
[image: bitmap intersection]

The design choice depends on the mix of workload (creation versus intersection). If the bitmaps are write once, read many times, then `std::unordered_set` will be vastly superior. On the other hand, if the workload is write once, read once, the `BitMap` might be better.

Here is the code I used for testing.

```cpp
#include <unordered_set>
#include "core/util/tool.h"
#include "core/util/random.h"
#include "core/chrono/stopwatch.h"

template<std::unsigned_integral T>
class BitReference {
public:
    using value_type = T;
    using pointer = value_type*;

    constexpr BitReference(pointer ptr, value_type mask)
        : ptr_(ptr)
        , mask_(mask) {
    }

    constexpr BitReference(const BitReference&) = default;

    constexpr BitReference& operator=(bool value) noexcept {
        if (value) *ptr_ |= mask_;
        else *ptr_ &= ~mask_;
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr BitReference& operator=(const BitReference& other) noexcept {
        if (other) *ptr_ |= mask_;
        else *ptr_ &= ~mask_;
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr bool operator~() const noexcept {
        return not (*ptr_ bitand mask_);
    }

    constexpr operator bool() const noexcept {
        return *ptr_ bitand mask_;
    }

    constexpr BitReference& flip() noexcept {
        if (*ptr_ bitand mask_) *ptr_ &= ~mask_;
        else *ptr_ |= mask_;
        return *this;
    }

private:
    constexpr BitReference();
    pointer ptr_;
    value_type mask_;
};

template<std::unsigned_integral T>
class BitMap {
public:
    using value_type = T;
    using pointer = value_type*;
    static constexpr auto bits_per_word_v = sizeof(T) * CHAR_BIT;

    BitMap(size_t nbits)
        : data_(words_for_nbits(nbits)) {
    }

    auto size() const {
        return nbits_;
    }

    auto nwords() const {
        return data_.size();
    }

    const value_type& operator()(size_t idx) const {
        return data_[idx];
    }

    bool operator[](size_t idx) const {
        auto [index, mask] = location(idx);
        return data_[index] bitand mask;
    }

    BitReference<value_type> operator[](size_t idx) {
        auto [index, mask] = location(idx);
        return BitReference<value_type>(&data_[0] + index, mask);
    }

private:
    static constexpr auto location(size_t idx) {
        auto index = idx / bits_per_word_v;
        auto mask = value_type{1} << (idx & bits_per_word_v);
        return std::make_pair(index, mask);
    }

    static constexpr auto words_for_nbits(size_t nbits) {
        return (bits_per_word_v + nbits - 1) / bits_per_word_v;
    }

    size_t nbits_;
    std::vector<value_type> data_;
};

template<class Work>
void measure(std::string_view desc, Work&& work) {
    size_t n{};
    chron::StopWatch timer;
    for (auto i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
        timer.mark();
        work();
        n += timer.elapsed_duration<std::chrono::nanoseconds>().count();
    }
    n /= 1'000;
    cout << fmt::format("{} {} ns", desc, n) << endl;
}

int tool_main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    ArgParse opts
        (
         argFlag<'v'>("verbose", "Verbose diagnostics")
         );
    opts.parse(argc, argv);

    using FullMap = BitMap<uint64_t>;
    using SparseMap = std::unordered_set<int>;
    constexpr auto NumberBits = 10'000;

    size_t sf{4};
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> d(0, NumberBits - 1);
    for (auto sparsity = 16; sparsity <= 1024; sparsity <<= 1, ++sf) {
        std::vector<int> bits_to_set(NumberBits / sparsity);
        std::generate(bits_to_set.begin(), bits_to_set.end(), [&]() { return d(core::rng()); });

        FullMap map(NumberBits);
        measure(fmt::format("create-map    {:6d} {:2d}", NumberBits, sf), [&]() {
            for (auto idx : bits_to_set)
                map[idx] = true;
            return map.size();
        });

        SparseMap set;
        measure(fmt::format("create-set    {:6d} {:2d}", NumberBits, sf), [&]() {
            for (auto idx : bits_to_set)
                set.insert(idx);
            return set.size();
        });

        FullMap map_b = map;
        FullMap map_r(NumberBits);
        measure(fmt::format("intersect-map {:6d} {:2d}", NumberBits, sf), [&]() {
            for (auto i = 0; i < map.nwords(); ++i)
                map_r = map(i) bitand map_b(i);
            return map_r.size();
        });

        SparseMap set_b = set;
        SparseMap set_r;
        measure(fmt::format("intersect-set {:6d} {:2d}", NumberBits, sf), [&]() {
            std::set_intersection(set.begin(), set.end(),
                                  set_b.begin(), set_b.end(),
                                  std::inserter(set_r, set_r.begin()));
            return set_r.size();
        });
    }

    return 0;
}
```